# How to use essentials buttons from add this

Tags: php, smarty, addthis

I am using [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) Sharing buttons in my web site . I am facing 2 small issues now.

1. After implementing the add this button at the end of the page url , I can see a new link as '#.UT_2jzd9X5I'. What is it? Is there any way to hide it?
2. How can I customize and use the essential AddThis share buttons in my web site.

For example I would like to use only the Facebook, Twitter, Digg, and StumbleUpon buttons. How can I customize which buttons are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random characters following the hash sign are to track referrals from visitors copy+pasting the URL. This can be disabled by including this line before you include the addthis javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};</script>
```

You can also change which share links are shown (taken from their [documentation](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#.UT_8ijvF3DY))

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
</div>
```